# How to action on excel popup windows by Autoit

Tags: autoit

am struggling since 2 days to action popup window of excel, how to write Autoitenter code here script to action on this popup windows

I tried below code but this is not working

```
WinWaitActive("Microsoft Excel") // enter the title of the pop up
Send("{ENTER}") / press enter
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below line to "Match any substring in the title" at the starting of script.

```
AutoItSetOption ("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
```

Comment: Girish, some how my earlier code is working, thanks for the suggestion